# Self-Signed Certificates in Spring-Boot

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I'm trying to get a Spring-Boot server up and running, which provides some security via SSL. I followed steps 1 and 2 of [this guide](https://www.drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/) to get a self-signed certificate and am able to access my site via `https`. The `application.properties` looks like this:

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.keyStore=classpath:keystore.p12
server.ssl.keyStorePassword=youd_want_to_know
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=hs
```

`keystore.p12` was generated with

```
$ keytool -genkey -alias hs -storetype PKCS12 \
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

Except for the password I didn't enter anything, all fields are "Unknown".

However, the lock in the browser isn't green. The detail message says

> There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).

The plus-side:

> Secure TLS connection
>   The connection to this site is using a strong protocol version and cipher suite.
>   Secure Resources
>   All resources on this page are served securely.

I guess in plain text it means that the data is transported securely, but the browser isn't fully happy with the certificate in terms of it can't track the authenticity. Therefore, I understand that this isn't worthy for production (and for now it doesn't need to be).

But, is it safe and secure for me since I own the server and know that I created the self-signed certificate myself? Or are there ways to turn this into a certificate that the browser is happy with? What do I need to do to make that work and what would the Sprint-Boot configuration look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Nutshell, 
Using a self signed certificate is completely unsafe unless

1. you control every machine between you and the server
   OR
2. you check that the keys in the certificate are what you expect them
   to be.

**Only advantage is**; it will block passive attacks (the attacker observes the data but does not alter it in any way) regardless of whether the CA certificate was issued by a mainstream CA or not.

Take a look here https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8112

Comment: Weird that I didn't find that question/answer.

Comment: From a certain perpective self signed certificates are much safer - not only if you control the hardware in between considered end points.

Comment: @Trinimon Can you elaborate a bit more please

Comment: @so-random-dude: basically the problem is, that you have to trust the certificate authority/ies. Unfortunately there is no guarantee that those companies get never hacked. In addition certificates might get stolen and abused for spoofing purposes. Concerning those aspects self signed certificates might be the better choice (check out _Application Security_ from O'Reilly).

Comment: @Trinimon I looked at someplaces, I couldn't find "Application Security" from O'Reilly. Do you mind posting a link here

Answer (score 3):

Thats how the browser is supposed to behave. As long as you (or rather, browsers you or your organization owns)  are the only consumers of your website, you are fine. But once you want to on-board other consumers you might need to get your certificate signed by a certificate provider

Answer (score 1):

In this case the communication between browser and server is still vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attack, so this not really "secure & safe"